# How good are graphene layers at shielding against ionizing radiation?

Tags: materials, radiation

I assume every materials laboratory has ways to test properties of new materials. Has anyone ever tested graphene's properties at shielding ionizing radiations? I guess It could be a good candidate due to tight packing of atoms

Comment: I just entered *graphene block ionizing radiation* into an internet search engine & got a number of references, some from Purdue University, another being a PhD thesis for Columbia University.

Comment: How good Is graphene at blocking ionizing radiations? Tungsten and Lead are better.. what a pity